# monitor or log database activities using sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, database, security, sql-server-2008

how i will moniter or see log of database.
i.e i want to moniter my all database activities like changes in database properties,query fired on tables and so on. done using any editor other than application.

i am using sql server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "sql server profiler" found under menu tools in sqlserver management studio